# Define a type with unsigned long parameter

Tags: excel, vba, long-integer, unsigned

I am developing an application with VBA for excel 2010 and I have the dll of a C third party application.

I need to call a function of the mentioned dll which takes a struct* as argument to return back values.

The signature:

```
fun_name(char[], int, T_CUSTOM_STRUCT)
```

where `T_CUSTOM_STRUCT` is composed of the following:

```
length: unsigned long
n_params: unsigned long
```

I have called many functions from this dll without problems but this is the first time I need to declare an unsigned long.
I created the struct in vba with the following code:

```
Type T_CUSTOM_STRUCT
   length As Long 
   n_params As Long
End Type
```

and I passed it to the function but it returns a FAIL. I suspect the problem is in the fact that VBA `Long` doesn't map an `C-unsigned Long`.

Is there a way in vba to declare an unsigned Long parameter?

Comment: Is that 32 or 64 bit? If 64 try [`LongLong` (8 byte)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type). `Long` in VBA is only `-2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647` (4 byte)

Comment: Unfortunately it is 32 bit

Comment: I believe the only unsigned integer data type for VBA is `Byte`.

Comment: Actually yes, VBA `Long` is always signed (you cannot declare a unsigned `Long`). @AndreaGiordano can you provide a [mcve]? Is there actually an error message?

Comment: The error I get is provided by the third-party library related to the function and it generally refers to a fail: that's why I am guessing on the reason why it fails. Unfortunately I cannot provide an example since it is a protected lib and my application itself runs on a non-accessible environment. I think maybe I could try with byte*4 as suggested by @RyanWildry